# Stylelint Order Issues: move certain properties at the top of the CSS declaration

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

we have stylelint in our proyect but its causing problems on one ocassion, when we use in the css the attributes (appearance, all) even though they are at the top of the css they are moved to the very bottom causing problems, for example it will remove the padding and cursor in the example below.

example

```
:host {
  ---company-icon-button-spacing: var(--company-icon-button-spacing, 10px);
}

button {
  appearance: none;
  all: unset;

  padding: var(---company-icon-button-spacing);

  cursor: pointer;
}
```

.stylelintrc.yml

```
extends:
  - stylelint-config-standard-scss
  - stylelint-config-rational-order
  - stylelint-config-prettier-scss
rules:
  # allow only custom properties with sab prefix (and triple dash internals)
  custom-property-pattern:
    - (?<=company-)
    - message: Expected kebab-case custom property name starting with "company-"
  # as we use :host selectors for declaration blocks exclusively, we may double them
  # we can't configure this, maybe we'll come up with some custom rule one day
  no-duplicate-selectors: null
  # we should use our own grid units, based on font-size sass function
  unit-disallowed-list:
    - [rem]
    - message: Use `utils.font-size` function instead of "%s"
  length-zero-no-unit: null
  declaration-empty-line-before: null
  order/properties-order:
    - []
    - severity: error
  plugin/rational-order:
    - [true]
    - empty-line-between-groups: true
```

We want to change the rule in the .stylelintrc.yml file to fix this problem, but so far it hasn't worked. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Partial Solution:

- if instead of using both (appearance, all) and just use "all" it will not be moved and will work.

Comment: I assume the problem comes from `plugin/rational-order`, you should open an issue on the plugin's repo if you believe it's a bug as there is no config that could fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [stylelint-config-recess-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-recess-order) shared config, rather than the [stylelint-config-rational-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-rational-order) one:

```
extends:
  - stylelint-config-standard-scss
  - stylelint-config-recess-order
  - stylelint-config-prettier-scss
```

The recess order config is maintained (last published 2 weeks ago), unlike the rational order config (last published 4 years ago). The recess order config supports modern CSS properties like `all`.

The two configs have similar groupings, i.e., they start with positioning, box model, typography, etc.